# Regex exclude character from the group

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to write this regex to match dots with a few rules

```
(\.+ *|([a-zA-ZÀ-ž]\.\d))(?=[^\d{1}(\.\d{1})])(?=[^.,])
```

But my regex is matching few characters before and after the dot as well

For example:

**č.1 > match č.1 (incorrect, match should be only .)**

**St.M > match . (correct)**

**2.0 > no match (correct)**

Do you have any idea, how to "exclude" these other characters from the result and match only the dot?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Like this? `(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ž])\.` https://regex101.com/r/xFiHID/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could shorten the pattern using a positive lookbehind `(?<=)` asserting the character class with the specific ranges to the left.

```
(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ž])\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xFiHID/1)

As per the comments, the pattern with the positive lookahead

```
(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ž])\.+ *(?=[^.,])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0obr4P/1)

Comment: I also added few more options to complete this - `(?<=[a-zA-ZÀ-ž])\.+ *(?=[^.,])`

Comment: @PetrJelínek I have added the pattern to the answer. Note that `\.+` matches 1 or more times a dot.